# Vs code default suggestions are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

when I type any html element or any javascript built in keyword ,any suggestion I am not getting

I tried "editor.quick suggestion":true and I have tried with reset all setting still not working

all those are efforts are not working

How to enable all defualt setting of vs code

Comment: Have you made sure the file type is correct?